# What is this bush with five-petaled pink flowers?

Tags: identification, trees, shrubs

My wife and I bought a house in the Palm Coast, Florida area. We have a plant growing by the house that the previous owner tried to kill, but could not. We think it is very pretty. We would like to know what it is, because no one at the nurseries can tell us. It grows very fast and is right next to our foundation. We would like to move it, because of it being by the foundation. I have included pictures of the plant and hope you can tell us what it is and if it's a bush or tree and the best location in the yard for it.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I am going to take no credit for this one. I first thought of some variation of Plumeria, but the trilobate leaf was fascinating, so I dug around Google a bit.

Someone on a garden forum nailed it on the head: Jatropha pandurifolia Andr.

Link here: http://forums2.gardenweb.com/discussions/1591259/3-lobed-leaf-on-tropical-plant

Surprised this was hard to kill, but looks like you'd rather move it, and I would hope you do, because the flowers look exquisite on close up. If you can dig down to the roots, and do it at the right time depending on your zone, you should be able to save the shrub.